# hashing library code assistance

Tags: java, regex, arraylist, project

I'm trying to figure out whats wrong with my code. its just not working the way I like to and I was wondering if someone could help me. what its supposed to do is store hash values of book titles and authors and to make sure not to insert duplicates into the library ArrayList. its just not working and I have no clue how to fix it.

```
    import java.util.*;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class HashTester {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        /*card.java code
        Card x = new Card("jack", "hearts");

        x.getHash();
        x.getEnglish();
        */
Library k = new Library();
ArrayList<BookHash> library = new ArrayList<BookHash>();

         BookHash y = new BookHash("moby dick", "jk rowling");
         BookHash y1 = new BookHash("harry potter", "lalala");
         BookHash y2 = new BookHash("moby dick", "jk rowling");
         k.listBooks();
         k.checkBook(y);
         k.checkBook(y1);
         k.checkBook(y2);
         k.listBooks();




    }




}


---------------

import java.util.*;
public class Library {


    public static ArrayList<BookHash> library = new ArrayList<BookHash>();
     BookHash g = new BookHash("moby dick", "jk rowling");

    public void checkBook(BookHash x){

        for(int i = 0; i <= library.get(i).getHashTitle() -1; i++){
            if(library.get(i + 1).getHashTitle()==(library.get(0).getHashTitle()) 
                    && library.get(i + 1).getHashAuthor() == (library.get(0).getHashAuthor())){
                System.out.println("book is used");
            }

            library.add(1, x);
        }
    }
    public void listBooks(){
        library.add(g);
        for(int i= 0; i< library.size(); i++){
            System.out.print( library.get(i).getHashTitle());
            System.out.print( library.get(i).getHashAuthor());

    }




}
```

---

```
public class BookHash {
    int hashTitle;
    int hashAuthor;


    BookHash(String title, String author){
        hashTitle = hashCode(title);
        hashAuthor = hashCode(author);
    }

    public int hashCode(String key){
        int hashNumber1 = 7;
        for(int i=0; i < key.length(); i++){
            hashNumber1 = hashNumber1*31 + key.charAt(i);

        }

                return hashNumber1;

    }
    public int getHashTitle(){
        return hashTitle;
    }
    public int getHashAuthor(){
        return hashAuthor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: What are you planning to da with the hashCode method from BookHash?

Answer (score 1):

Your class BookHash needs to overwrite the hashCode() and equals() methods of the class Object. Normally you can generate these methods with your IDE.

Then you can use the contains(Object o) method of the ArrayList to check if the Object is already contained. => Shortens the checkBook-Method

Or you use a Set. A Set can only contain each object once. If you add an object to a Set, the Set checks if it is already in. => No need for the checkBook-Method

Java 8 Doc of Set: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

You can use a HashSet for instance.

Java 8 Doc of HashSet: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

I found an error in your checkBook-Method.
You compare Strings with == instead of .equals().
Use the equals method of Objects, if one of the two objects you compare could be null.
See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html

It should be like that:

```
if(Objects.equals(library.get(i + 1).getHashTitle(), library.get(0).getHashTitle()) 
   && Objects.equals(library.get(i + 1).getHashAuthor(), library.get(0).getHashAuthor()) {
       System.out.println("book is used");
}
```

But it would be much easier to overwrite the hashCode and equals method and use the contains-method of ArrayList or to use a HashSet.

I hope this helps. :-)